# What is the "click.smoothscroll" event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen the following code:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click.smoothscroll',function(e) {...}
```

I do not understand what the click.something is.
I know the function like this:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e) {...}
```

what is the something/smoothscroll doing? is this a kind of event?

Comment: It's a custom click event,more like a namespace. If you bind it to an element,you can unbind only that particular event,without effecting other click events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a namespacing for your event handlers, consider you have multiple handlers to your element:

```
$('#element').on('click', f);
$('#element').on('click', g);
$('#element').on('click', h);
```

- `[!]` Consider `f`, `g`, `h` as anonymous function: `function () { }`.

As you can see, if you click the `#element`, three functions (`f`, `g`, `h`) will fire.
Now you want to remove function `g` from your `click`.
How to do that? It not possible. But if you do a namespacing with it:

```
$('#element').on('click.type1', f);
$('#element').on('click.type2', g);
$('#element').on('click.type1', h);
```

As you see, I put `f` and `h` in a group, and `g` in another group, then I can unbind it from my element:

```
$('#element').off('click.type2');
```

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 2):

`smoothscroll` in this case is a namespace. So in case you want to remove click event, but don't want to affect other events that are attached you can safely do by calling:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').off('click.smoothscroll');
```

To remove all events that are attached to the element in that namespace simply call:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').off('.smoothscroll');
```

Comment: are there reserved namespaces or can i use smoothscroll for my own?

Comment: You can use any name you want.